# Transaction not being mined on Ropsten

Tags: transactions, mining, testnets, ropsten

I initiated a transaction shown below on the Ropsten network on 20th december but it has still not been mined

```
eth.getTransaction("0x03be33da1534059365be44459153829fce0e0ff1f9423a5f823c048dae680f4d")

{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x39000b406ef0b3602a36eac3126ede1873b1a550",
  gas: 136158,
  gasPrice: 46000000000,
  hash: "0x03be33da1534059365be44459153829fce0e0ff1f9423a5f823c048dae680f4d",
  input: "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000096d495e9573520626e8432c63184f6de13d7a8b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014",
  nonce: 16,
  r: "0xc826a6f48d396876225c0a0e42d3e1db01b89291720df4075105fd57d1a7c960",
  s: "0x6fa6fe7904114eba91a717327aa5d9862dd01dbd36afa683d345c8ed9ddb6ec7",
  to: "0xeb1dcb768c1656721aeb0c1a727e84e0fec82ec7",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x29",
  value: 0
}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: how did you initiate this transaction?

Comment: it is a transfer of tokens from one account to another. I used Ethereum wallet for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This transaction in pending in geth txpool (from that transaction was broadcast).

Due to high nonce the current nonce is 14 and this transaction nonce is 16.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Ethereum and Ropsten and I had the same problem. I waited for two days for my test contract transaction to complete. When I simply started to mine some test Ether again, my transaction completed in couple of minutes since I started mining. I think I might have mined my own transaction? ;) I wish I figured that out two days ago.